# What is React Native Web?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

As per the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/)

> React Native is there to Create native apps for Android and iOS
> using React.

But I'm confused with React Native Web.
As per the [github home](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)

> "React Native for Web" makes it possible to run React Native components and APIs on the web using React DOM.

I'm not getting!

Is this an officially supported library by React Native to compile React Native Mobile Apps, as Web Apps to run on the Web from the same code base, like we do in Flutter?

Comment: You cannot run react-native project in a browser. You need to run emulators or connect a real device to get it work. React native web is for running react native projects in a web browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that to debug a React Native project you have to run it on an emulator (Expo, Android emulator...). With `react-native-web` is no longer necessary! You can run your React Native project directly in your browser!

Comment: Ok But is that feature for just testing purposes during development or we can Deploy our React Native Apps as Web Apps to production environments?

Comment: Ciao, it's just for testing purpose.